# How to refresh Cognito session in async function that needs to return valid credentials

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, amazon-cognito, apollo, aws-appsync

I have a function that runs right after I configure my Redux store:

```
function configureApollo(store) {

  return new AWSAppSyncClient({
    url: AppSync.graphqlEndpoint,
    region: AppSync.region,
    auth: {

    credentials: async () => {//...code that returns valid credentials}

    }
  })
}
```

I'm using react-cognito to manage credentials and it stores them in the redux store under `store.getState().cognito.creds`. My problem is when credentials are expired and need to be refreshed, react-cognito exports a function `performLogin` which  returns a promise for a "COGNITO_LOGIN" action which has a payload with refreshed credentials.

I feel like I should be dispatching the returned action and pulling the new credentials from the store after it's updated, but dispatch has no callback.

I think I can read the credentials out of the COGNITO_LOGIN action, dispatch the action, and never worry about reading the credentials from `store.getState()`

```
const resultAction = await performLogin(user, config, group);

store.dispatch(resultAction);
return new AWSCredentials(
  {
    accessKeyId: resultAction.creds.accessKeyId,
    secretAccessKey: resultAction.creds.secretAccessKey,
    sessionToken: resultAction.creds.sessionToken
  })
```

...but this seems wrong. What if there is an error in the reducer saving the credentials to the store? Then my AWSAppSyncClient has credentials that are out of sync with the rest of my app.

Is there a better approach here?

Answer (score 3):

If you use the `aws-amplify` libraries, it's a lot easier.  Take a look at the section on authentication in the README.md at https://github.com/aws/aws-amplify#2-add-authentication-to-your-app to use it to add AWS Cognito authentication to your app.  After that, you can configure the credentials for AWS AppSync via the following

```
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';
import AWSAppSyncClient from 'aws-appsync';
import { AUTH_TYPE } from 'aws-appsync/lib/link/auth-link'
import AppSync from './AppSync.js';

const client = new AWSAppSyncClient({
    url: AppSync.graphqlEndpoint,
    region: AppSync.region,
    auth: {
        type: AUTH_TYPE.AWS_IAM,
        credentials: () => Auth.currentCredentials()
    },
    complexObjectsCredentials: () => Auth.currentCredentials(),
});
```

Comment: More and more I'm thinking of transitioning to Amplify. I'm using react-cognito currently because I thought it's Redux integration would be useful but it's becoming more of a pain than it's worth.

Comment: About a year ago, I was in the same boat you are currently in - back then, I don't even think the `aws-amplify` libraries were even available for use (or if they were, they weren't ready for prime time).  Since I've switched to using `aws-amplify`, setting up authentication and AWS service access has been easy as pie - I don't use AWS Mobile Hub if I can manage, though.  I usually provision my cloud resources using CloudFormation and use the outputs from that to generate my configuration files.